# Find the first version of an artifact (jar) that contains a class

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, versioning

We need to find the first version of a jar which contains a particular class. For eg., if Class A was first packaged into A-1.jar, I need A-1.jar. Problem being Class A would now might have been packaged and versioned multiple times, and maybe at, say, A-3.1.jar. And A-3.1.jar is what I will find on searching, and not A-1.jar. A-1.jar is needed because it may come with less frills, i.e, dependencies. The latest versions may contain dependencies which the working project does not need/cannot have, as it may lead to multiple changes in the project. Is there any dependency tool which can help with this? Thank you!

Comment: Your motivation seems strange: Why do you expect earlier versions of a project to be more compatible? I would always try to use newer versions with less bugs.

Comment: Because the project is legacy, all existing dependencies are old. Now unfortunately we can't go big bang and migrate all components of the project to newer tech in a go. As part of this phase based on business reqs, migrating a single component. When the next component will be migrated is a long shot.

Comment: So wouldn't it be better to not look for the oldest version, but look at the dependencies and see whether you find a version with fitting dependencies?

Comment: Then if I add those fitting dependencies, they start to clash with the existing old dependencies and start creating further build issues..

Comment: But what does it help you to have the first version with a given class? It will also have dependencies. Why do you expect this version to be any better than others?

Comment: Eg: Hibernate aggregator artifact, say 3.2.5, does not have jboss logging dependency. But as the incremental versioning began, it shed the aggregator artifacts and we had core/annotations and other artifacts which had logging. If one uses the newer artifacts, not only does one need to include logging dependency, but would also need to add more jars to support other dependencies of Spring. Now as I said, we wont be having these problems if we upgrade all the frameworks in a go, but its a business constraint at the moment. Well yea, some projects are still out there waiting for redemption..

Comment: It may be true for hibernate, it may be the other way round for other artifacts. Personally, I would look for versions which have roughly the age of your project and hope that these are the best fit.